# Get total count of distance with overlapping ranges excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerbi

I am trying to find a way to calculate the total distance from overlapping ranges. I have attached an image to help explain this. Essentially I want to know how much of my given range has an object on it.

[image: Excel Example]

Using the example above with my total range being 35. There is an object from 0-5 and 3-15. Meaning there is an object from 0-15. And From 20-27, 27-32, 17-24, meaning this object is 17-32.

**Giving us:**

0-15 = 15

17-32 = 15

=a total distance of 30 out of my total range of 35.

Being able to get a total distance would be enough, otherwise if there is a way to merge the ranges that overlap and then I can calculate from there.

I am using Excel or PowerBI to do this so a solution in either of these would be very helpful. Have seen some solutions using dates but they seem to only work for 2 dates and not more. My data will potentially have 100s of records.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! As far as I can see, 35 (the right end of your range) doesn't appear anywhere in the Objects table. Are you setting this value somewhere separately? Or is it the result of rounding up the end of Object4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's count the lengths of all subranges **Not Overlapped by any Object**, and then subtract this value from the total length of the entire range.

Important! As long as the objects in the table are listed in an arbitrary order, the formula will give an incorrect result. Therefore, first sort the table in ascending column **To**

Now, from the beginning of each object, subtract the end of the previous object. Let's do this not for one cell, but for the entire range at once:

[image: Subtract ranges]

*(I added rows with the beginning of the range and its end for clarity)*

We are not interested in overlapping areas, so we will get rid of negative numbers using the IF() function. The total sum of positive values will be obtained using the {SUM()} function (as an Array Function!):

`{=SUM(IF(B3:B8-C2:C7>0;B3:B8-C2:C7;0))}`

For the value set in question, this will return **5**

Now `35(end) - 0(start) - 5 = 30`

Answer (score 0):

A different way to do it would be to collect the left sides of the "20-27" type expressions and find their minimum (`MIN`) and do the same for the right side and find their maximum (`MAX`). Subtract the minimum from the maximum and add 1 for the number of cells used in all the ranges, counting each one only once.

It will NOT account for gaps as probably `JohnSUN`'s approach will though I read the problem as gaps not being something to consider possible.

For example, using the latest and the greatest:

```
=VALUE(MAX(VALUE(TEXTAFTER(IF(C4:E4="",$C$4,C4:E4),"-"))+1) - MIN(VALUE(TEXTBEFORE(IF(C4:E4="",$C$4,C4:E4),"-"))))
```

which, very strangely, insists upon changing formatting to Text upon pressing Enter! Changing formatting back to General and coercing the change with F2-Enter does then give a result and that result cell can be copied and pasted without further aggravation, though editing it... and no obvious reason why such a thing can and does happen.

So, for entries in the range C4:E4, it gives the total distance. One could widen that range to include as many inputs as one wishes. And cells in the input range can be empty.

For the values themselves, something slightly different:

```
=INDIRECT(  "A"  &  MIN(VALUE(TEXTBEFORE(IF($C$4:$E$4="",$C$4,$C$4:$E$4),"-")))  &  ":A"  &  MAX(VALUE(TEXTAFTER(IF($C$4:$E$4="",$C$4,$C$4:$E$4),"-"))))
```

where one would place whatever column letter was needed for a column of data, or reverse the logic for row data (so finding columns instead of rows).

For that matter, one could use the latter formula inside a `ROWS` function to find only the total distance.

Not as elegant, and will not notice gaps, but, different, and perhaps easier to apply in related, but differing circumstances. Perhaps.

Also, it would be a BEAST of an approach if one has not the latest text manipulation functions. Highly affected also by users not sticking to using the hyphen...

Comment: "gaps not being something to consider possible" attached picture clearly shows a gap